# Estimating modulus from integer approximation

Tags: number-theory

I want to calculate $NM^{-1}\bmod q$ as efficiently as possible.

However, I have only $N+\delta$,$M+\mu$ with $\delta,\mu>0$ arbitrarily small.

How accurately can I estimate $NM^{-1}\bmod q$?

Factors of $q$ not known.